# Translation of "That will never work"

Tags: traducción

I'm not sure about the best way to translate "that will never work" and similar phrases with a vague "that" as the subject (like "that's not a good idea" or "that's the third time he said it"). Should I just leave the subject off ("no va a funcionar")?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*"That will never work"* can be translated as:

> Eso nunca funcionará (*That will never work*).
>
> Eso nunca va a funcionar (*That is never going to work*)

The other sentences you listed can be similarly translated as:

> Eso no es una buena idea (*That is not a good idea*).
>
> Esa es la tercera vez que él lo dijo (*That is the third time he said it*).

You can omit the "Eso" (that) as you have done and the sentence will still be correct, provided it is clear what "*that*" refers to.

Comment: Okay thanks, good to know. I guess I thought something more complicated was going on.